# With restFB, is there a way to get a list of all valid facebook IDs or to check if a random ID is valid?

Tags: java, facebook, validation, restfb

I'm exploring restFB and wanna create a Java statement which will return a list of all valid Facebook IDs. Beside, I want also to check if a randomly generated chain of digits is a valid Facebook ID. How can I do that with Java using restFB API?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just get a list of all valid Facebook IDs. They are non-incremental and different IDs map to different objects, so there is no way to get all IDs that resolve to a user.

You can always just fetch the ID and inspect the response (`https://graph.facebook.com/<ID>`). But, please be aware that scraping is against the policy and there are automated systems in place to detect such behaviour.

Also, there is a rate-limiting for making requests; so requesting all the IDs in series will definitely get you (temporarily) blocked.

Bottom line; you can't do this and if you could it's also not allowed by Facebook.